# How to call jQuery Function from Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
function go() 
{
window.location=document.getElementById("menu").value;
}
</script>

<body>
<form>
<select id="menu" onchange="go()">
  <option>--Select a page--</option>
  <option value="http://www.1.com">1</option>
  <option value="http://www.2.com">2</option>
  <option value="http://www.3.com">3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
```

this works perfectly, but I cant call the function from External File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function go(){
window.location=document.getElementById("menu").value;
}});
```

Comment: what do you mean by external file??

Comment: jQuery or JavaScript file

Comment: You didnt close the document ready function properly...$(document).ready(function() {
    function go(){
window.location=document.getElementById("menu").value;
}});

Comment: Simply call it like you are, just make sure you include the `script` AFTER your HTML

Comment: What does the console say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By putting `function go(){}" inside of "$(document).ready(function() {`  you enclosing the the go function within the scope of `$(document).ready(function() {}`

Use `document.ready()` to call a function, not to declare it.

Answer (score 3):

Add an Event-Hanlder to your Script like

```
$('#menu').on('onchange', function()
{
 // do something
}
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').on('onchange', function()
    {
       window.location=document.getElementById("menu").value;
    }
});
```

And your HTML looks like:

```
<select id="menu">
      <option>--Select a page--</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">1</option>
      <option value="http://www.2.com">2</option>
      <option value="http://www.3.com">3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

No it's jquery but it's very simple!

```
<select id="menu" onchange="document.location.href = this.value">
      <option>--Select a page--</option>
      <option value="http://www.google.com">1</option>
      <option value="http://www.2.com">2</option>
      <option value="http://www.3.com">3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#menu').find(":selected").text()`;